# Is there a way to change Notification Settings globally?

Tags: notifications

I'd like to disable only certain aspects for ALL notifications.  For example, I'd like to disable all Bubbles for notifications. It'd be nice to have a master switch for just that, but would like to leave Sounds on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These options exist.

1. Right click on the notification icon in the top right corner
2. Click `Notifications settings`
3. Click on the `Other` icon which should handle all additional apps

Admittedly you still need to change settings for `EOS apps` individually

I don't know about you, but I only have 9 other apps to do manually. I agree you should make a feature request for global settings, but that is not for the EOS Stack Exchange.